# system_tray to receive notifications of device removal

Tags: c#, c, winapi, device-driver, systray

I'm writing an application which check for my usb device and if the device is avialable make a dial-up connection. I use `Rasdial` to establish the connection. Unfortunately if I remove the USB cable the connection is not getting disconnected or notified to the user. So here 
I'm in a situation to check for the `device removal`.

I Planned to run my application in system tray and wait for the device removal. Am I right here?

If am right how to make the application wait for device removal, currently my console application exits once the dial-up connection is made. How to achieve this in Winapi32? Am coding it in C.

Comment: The title doesn't seem to match the actual question (which I beleive is a duplicate of your previous questions?) Please update thw question or title to suit.

Comment: Better. The system tray still doesn't come into it though as that's purely a UI choice.

Comment: No my question belongs to system tray. I want my app to be in system tray and monitors the device removal. there is no UI in my current app at all...

Comment: As I said, the system tray has no bearing on whether you can receive device disconnection notifications. I don't know off hand how you register to receive them if the `registerdevicenotification()` [you've used before](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11151183/588306) doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your window can handle the `WM_DEVICECHANGE` broadcast message to tell when something has changed. If you need more detailed information, use `RegisterDeviceNotification()`.

Using the system notification area has no bearing on your ability to use these methods. They all require a window to send the notifications to, but it can be kept hidden.

Comment: ya if I hide the window its like running my app background rit?? just to get the window handle I went for system tray. But you mean even I can avoid that? Please correct me If am wrong..

Comment: Well, the system notification tray needs a window to send its messages back to. It doesn't magically give you one.

Comment: this comment may sounds outta place to this post forgive me if so.. Is there a way to find only my device insertion/removal using "registerdevicenotififcation". Can you please give me some tips on it?

Comment: It depends how you identify your device. That API can filter on device class, it's up to you to detect the actual device by the information it sends you.