# How to detect when new hardware is connected in Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi

Is there a mechanism in Windows that allows applications to detect when new hardware is connected to the system? In particular I would like to detect:

- any serial ports being connected/disconnected
- my custom USB-to-I2C board which uses WinUSB

Comment: tinman: Not or. WM_DEVICECHANGE messages aren't broadcast for all devices, only for disks and serial/parallel ports (including USB-based virtual COM ports). For other devices, the notification is sent only to windows for which it's been requested.

Comment: See this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11223562/588306)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want [`RegisterDeviceNotification`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363431%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and `WM_DEVICECHANGE`.

Comment: This is a great starting point (RegisterDeviceNotification). Can you give me a clue in which direction to search for custom devices?

Comment: @tinman: oops, maybe serial ports are sent automatically also.  *Most* device types aren't.

Comment: I found an explanation, and saw your updated comment, in the MSDN page you linked to the last paragraph in remarks has "The DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL and DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE events are automatically broadcast to all top-level windows for port devices." So that explains the serial ports. I'll remove my previous comment.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14500/Detecting-Hardware-Insertion-and-or-Removal , this might help you..